# how to call a function of javascript in view of codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
<script type="application/x-javascript">
    addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false);
    function hideURLbar() {
        window.scrollTo(0,1);
    }
</script>
```

I have that script. I want to call it in codeigniter view.
How can I call it by `baseurl()` or any thing else?

Comment: i have done that before but its not helpfull i want to call it in view of codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Include script into HTML by using `base_url()` function

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/listener.js'); ?>"></script>
```

Is this what your looking for? if not Explain further.

Comment: i dont have src i have function